# Getting data from mongodb/mongoose using predefined functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, typescript

This is how I am currently getting data from mongodb:

```
users.get(base_URL, (req, res) => {
    UserModel.find({}, (err, docs) => {
        res.render("Users/index", {
            title: "All Users here",
            user_list: docs
        });
    });
});
```

Now, as you can see this is an express application. What I would like, is to simple call a function so that I can get the value from the `docs` variable inside the mongodb model callback. How do I do this, ideally, I want to see something like this:

```
users.get(base_URL, (req, res) => {
    res.render('<some_jade_file_here>', {
            title: "Yes, got it right",
            user_list: getAllUsers();
        });
});
```

Ideally, I just want to call a function. How can I do this, since having to put render inside of a mongodb call is a problem, since you may want to query a bunch of things from the database, and it might not even be just one database. I'm struggling a little since I'm not all that used to callbacks.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. If you're wondering about this syntax `() => {}`, thats just an anonymous function in typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without callbacks, but you can use an async flow control library like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) to help manage the nest of callbacks.  In this case you probably want to use [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel).

Using that you can do something like:

```
users.get(base_URL, (req, res) => {
    var data = {
        title: "Yes, got it right"
    };
    async.parallel([
        (callback) => {
            UserModel.find({}, (err, docs) {
                data.user_list = docs;
                callback(err);
            });
        },
        (callback) => {
            // Other query that populates another field in data
        }
    ], (err, results) => {
        // Called after all parallel functions have called their callback
        res.render('<some_jade_file_here>', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Will get back to you ASAP.